# How to give space between inputs in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hi i have created radio button in my material template but i am not able to get label and radio button on same line why what is the problem can anyone suggest me

Here its my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wb8vpbc3/9/

```
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <label class="">Employees</label>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input id="radio1" name="radio" type="radio" checked class="custom-control-input">
                    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                    <span class="custom-control-description"> 0 - 50</span>
                  </label>
                  <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                    <span class="custom-control-description">50 - 100</span>
                  </label>
                  <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input id="radio3" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                    <span class="custom-control-description">100 - 250</span>
                  </label>
                  <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input id="radio4" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                    <span class="custom-control-description">250 - 500</span>
                  </label>
                  <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input id="radio5" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                    <span class="custom-control-description">500 - 1000</span>
                  </label>
                  <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input id="radio6" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                    <span class="custom-control-description">above 1000</span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: did you tried using css?

Comment: I see them on the same line actually. What is your problem ?

Comment: no see it in full page its not on same line Boris

Answer (score 0):

I think the `<div class="form-check">` not helping you to achieve what you want

edited fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/wb8vpbc3/11/

```
       <section id="wrapper">
  <div class="login-register" style="background-image:url(../assets/images/background/login-register.jpg);">
    <div class="col-10"  style="margin:0 auto; top:0px;">
      <div class="card company">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-info pull-right">skip</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="text-center">
            <h4 class="card-title text-info">Tell us more about your Company</h4>
          </div>

          <form class="m-t-40">

            <div class="row floating-labels">
              <div class="col-4">
                <div class="form-group m-b-40">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input5">
                  <span class="bar"></span>
                  <label for="input5">Phone Number</label>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-4">
                <div class="form-group m-b-40">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input6">
                  <span class="bar"></span>
                  <label for="input6">Ext</label>
                </div>
              </div>

               <div class="col-4">
                <div class="form-group m-b-40">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success">+</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <label class="">Employees   </label>
                  <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input id="radio1" name="radio" type="radio" checked class="custom-control-input">
                    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                    <span class="custom-control-description"> 0 - 50</span>
                  </label>
                  <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                    <span class="custom-control-description">50 - 100</span>
                  </label>
                  <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input id="radio3" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                    <span class="custom-control-description">100 - 250</span>
                  </label>
                  <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input id="radio4" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                    <span class="custom-control-description">250 - 500</span>
                  </label>
                  <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input id="radio5" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                    <span class="custom-control-description">500 - 1000</span>
                  </label>
                  <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input id="radio6" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                    <span class="custom-control-description">above 1000</span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: its ok need some between button and label